# Deployment for salesforce org using SFDX plugin

Tags: salesforce

[

```
** Creating meta.xml files **
{
  status: 500,
  error: Error: Unable to create /BuildFiles/Templates/package.xml Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/BuildFiles/Templates/package.xml'
```

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj9tV.png)

Comment: We have no idea what that "directbook" is, you'll have to contact the vendor of this solution? You are using some script around "pure" sfdx. Maybe you have to create the directory manually before it can run? or grant file permissions?

Comment: @eyescream 'directbook' this is plugin we r using for deployment. Which directory we need to create?